# Woocommerce Subscriptions pay without logging in

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I'd like to allow anyone to pay for their initial subscription order without having to log in.

I've tried adding this snipet to my website but it doesn't work:

https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-allow-to-pay-for-order-without-login/

It works for orders but not for parent orders of a subscription.

Answer (score 0):

After exploring WooCommerce Subscriptions Core code I'm convinced that this it not possible. The plugin enforces that the user needs to be logged in to pay for the parent order of a subscription.

See [wcs-cart-initial-payment](https://github.com/Automattic/woocommerce-subscriptions-core/blob/trunk/includes/class-wcs-cart-initial-payment.php)

Answer (score 0):

The solution mentioned in the article you linked to only works for regular WooCommerce orders and not for subscriptions, which are a separate product type in WooCommerce and have different payment requirements.

You may find this guide on guest checkout for WooCommerce subscriptions helpful:

https://simongondeck.com/woocommerce-subscriptions-guest-checkout/

Or, if you are more of a visual learner, follow along with this video tutorial that outlines everything described in the article:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=twqdtHu5TqQ&ab_channel=SimonGondeck

Comment: Doesn't work for me because ir requires a new user account to be created, whereas I want to add subscriptions to existing users without asking them to login.